# Why does the C# compiler not even warn about endless recursion?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, infinite-loop, compiler-warnings

A legacy app is in an endless loop at startup; I don't know why/how yet (code obfuscation contest candidate), but regarding the method that's being called over and over (which is called from several other methods), I thought, "I wonder if one of the methods that calls this is also calling another method that also calls it?"

I thought: "Nah, the compiler would be able to figure that out, and not allow it, or at least emit a warning!"

So I created a simple app to prove that would be the case:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        method1();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        method2();
    }

    private void method1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method1 called, which will now call method2");
        method2();
    }

    private void method2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method2 called, which will now call method1");
        // Note to self: Write an article entitled, "Copy-and-Paste Considered Harmful"
        method1();
    }
}
```

...but no! It compiles just fine. Why wouldn't the compiler flag this code as questionable at best? If either button is mashed, you are in never-never land!

Okay, sometimes you may *want* an endless loop (pacemaker code, etc.), but still I think a warning should be emitted.

Comment: The most basic thing of any graphical user interface is based on an endless loop, an event loop. There is really no reason why the compiler should warn you about this because there are many useful situations for this. And also, your code isn’t endlessly looping, it’s interrupted by message boxes.

Comment: Detecting an endless loop in general is undecidable. It's a consequence of Rice's theorem.

Comment: I didn't even know Condoleeza was a coder. Or did you mean Jerry?

Comment: That's not an endless loop, but an endless recursion. And this is much worse, since it leads to a stack overflow. An endless recursion is never desired, unless you are programming malware.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Aha! That is what I meant, I reckon. So why doesn't the compiler warn about endless recursion? That would be helpful. Are there any tools that will, since the won't compiler won't?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon That is also an insolvable problem.  You're attempting to solve the halting problem, a famously proved unsolvable problem.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: This is tail recursion. Any descent compiler can compress the call stack by simply overwriting the last call frame.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Recursion is often converted to iteration, though.  It's possible here, since these are tail calls.

Comment: @CommuSoft Not necessarily, and C# doesn't.  Among other things, you need to consider exceptions, which need to report an accurate call stack.

Comment: But you can not, in the general case, prove that it is an endless recursion. It is not even obvious that this code actually causes an endless recursion - `MessegeBox.Show()` could for example throw an exception and exit the recursion.

Comment: @CommuSoft: "Any descent compiler" <= Assuming this is one that has been thrown off a cliff, I sometimes feel like making this one such.

Comment: @Servy: Well even then, there are academic languages who are able to emit reasonable error messages but still support tail recursion. For instance Prolog.

Comment: Note that even much simple sample does not emit any warnings: `int Foo {get {...}; set {Foo=value;}}`.

Comment: @Servy .Net supports tail recursion there is an explicit prefix: "tail.". The x64 jit sometimes even uses it when not explicitly told to do so.

Comment: In `Debug` mode optimizations are turned off.

Comment: The complier can only base its warnings and errors on static analysis of the code text. It cannot take into account code modified by the optimizer. Optimizations (like tail call optimization) are performed in a later stage of the compiling process (if at all). In fact most optimizations are performed when producing machine code from IL code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not an endless loop, but an endless recursion. And this is much worse, since they can lead to a stack overflow. Endless recursions are not desired in most languages, unless you are programming malware. Endless loops, however, are often intentional. Services typically run in endless loops.

In order to detect this kind of situation, the compiler would have to analyze the code by following the method calls; however the C# compiler limits this process to the immediate code within the current method. Here, uninitialized or unused variables can be tracked and unreachable code can be detected, for instance. There is a tradeoff to make between the compiling speed and the depth of static analysis and optimizations.

Also it is hardly possible to know the real intention of the programmer.

Imagine that you wrote a method that is perfectly legal. Suddenly because you are calling this method from another place, your compiler complains and tells you that your method is no more legal. I can already see the flood of posts on SO like: "My method compiled yesterday. Today it does not compile any more. But I didn't change it".

Comment: That's more like a circular reference recursion (I mean OP's posted code).

Comment: This is just a special case of a recursion.

Comment: "it is hardly possible to know the real intention of the programmer" It's usually safe to assume the worst, it seems.

Comment: Some situations which might seem bad, can be intentional and still make sense in certain situations. The compiler is not intelligent in the human sense, it is just a machine.

Comment: If compilers were to start complaining about bad code, dev computers all around the world would worn out on the sudden flood of warning messages. :)

Comment: Lets imagine we're making an application with a user interface. That user interface is written in Lisp. Chances are, we have an endless recursion in here (maybe converted to a loop, but that isn't important) to keep the UI visible, and that it is not malware. Endless recursion does, in fact, have uses outside malware.

Comment: For me as a C#, VB, VBA and former Pascal, Modula-2, Oberon-2 programmer the idea of a legal endless recursion seems absurd; however, things might be different in languages like LISP (which I perceive as rather exotic, personally).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I agree most of the time it's possible to turn a recursive call into a loop.

Comment: @Crono: Yes; however, the problem is that you cannot rely on compiler optimizations, unless the optimization is part of the language specification itself. If the LISP specifications says that recursions will be converted to loops, you can safely use an endless recursion. This is comparable to the shortcut evaluation in C#. In C# `i < N && a[i] == x` is okay, because it is specified that the second term will not be evaluated if the first is false. If it was only a technical detail of the complier, but not specified as part of the language, you would have to write `i < N ? a[i] == x : false`.

Comment: It is not a matter of optimized code, it is a matter of correctness.

Answer (score 12):

1. As you said sometimes people want infinite loops. And the jit-compiler of .net supports tailcall optimization, so you might not even get a stack overflow for endless recursion like you did it.
2. For the general case, predicting whether or not a program is going to terminate at some point or stuck in an infinite loop is impossible in finite time. It's called the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). All a compiler can possibly find are some special cases, where it is easy to decide.

Comment: It's not impossible only in finite time, it's impossible period.

Answer (score 7):

To put it very simply: **it's not the compiler's job to question your coding patterns**.

You could very well write a `Main` method that does nothing but throw an `Exception`. It's a far easier pattern to detect and a much more stupid thing to do; yet the compiler will happily allow your program to compile, run, crash and burn.

With that being said, since technically an endless loop / recursion is perfectly legal as far as the compiler is concerned, there's no reason why it should complain about it.

Actually, it would be very hard to figure out at compile time that the loop can't ever be broken at runtime. An exception could be thrown, user interaction could happen, a state might change somewhere on a specific thread, on a port you are monitoring, etc... there's way too much possibilities for any code analysis tool out there to establish, without any doubt, that a specific recursing code segment will inevitably cause an overflow at runtime.

I think the right way to prevent these situations is through unit testing organization. The more code paths you are covering in your tests, the less likely you are to ever face such a scenario.

Comment: “it's not the compiler's job to question your coding patterns” Isn't that exactly what warnings are for? To highlight coding patterns that are valid, but are very likely wrong.

Comment: @svick it depends what you call a coding pattern. To me a var that's never assigned or an obsolete member being used aren't design issues.

Answer (score 3):

Because its nearly impossible to detect!

In the example you gave, it is obvious (to us) that the code will loop forever. But the compiler just sees a function call, it doesn't necessarily know at the time what calls that function, what conditional logic could change the looping behavior etc.

For example, with this slight change you aren't in an infinite loop anymore:

```
private bool method1called = false;
private void method1()
{
    MessageBox.Show("method1 called, which will now call method2");

    if (!method1called)
       method2();

    method1called = true;
}

private void method2()
{
    MessageBox.Show("method2 called, which will now call method1");
    method1();
}
```

Without actually running the program, how would you know that it isn't looping? I could potentially see a warning for `while (true)`, but that has enough valid use cases that it also makes sense to not put a warning in for it.

A compiler is just parsing the code and translating to IL (for .NET anyways). You can get limited information like variables not being assigned while doing that (especially since it has to generate the symbol table anyways) but advanced detection like this is generally left to code analysis tools.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Infinite Loop Wiki found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Intentional_looping

> There are a few situations when this is desired behavior. For example, the games on cartridge-based game consoles typically have no exit condition in their main loop, as there is no operating system for the program to exit to; the loop runs until the console is powered off.
>
> Antique punchcard-reading unit record equipment would literally halt once a card processing task was completed, since there was no need for the hardware to continue operating, until a new stack of program cards were loaded.
>
> By contrast, modern interactive computers require that the computer constantly be monitoring for user input or device activity, so at some fundamental level there is an infinite processing idle loop that must continue until the device is turned off or reset. In the Apollo Guidance Computer, for example, this outer loop was contained in the Exec program, and if the computer had absolutely no other work to do it would loop running a dummy job that would simply turn off the "computer activity" indicator light.
>
> Modern computers also typically do not halt the processor or motherboard circuit-driving clocks when they crash. Instead they fall back to an error condition displaying messages to the operator, and enter an infinite loop waiting for the user to either respond to a prompt to continue, or to reset the device.

Hope this helps.